# How to convert string parameters to integer at one time on Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have following error, when I get parameters from form, then using `Multi.insert(:insert, game)`;

```
value `"12"` for `Server.Sample.Game.team_id` in `insert` does not match type :id
```

I got params like this. Then put `team_id` on Game map.

```
game = %Game{team_id: attrs["team_id"], ....}
Multi.new()
  |> Multi.insert(:insert, game)
  |> Repo.transaction()
```

Of course, I thought type error team_id should be integer, but string.
My question is if there are lot of strings, should I convert string to integer each?

I would like to find best way convert to integer each items.

Thanks.

Comment: Before you insert your data into the database you should pass it through an [Ecto.Changeset](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) calling cast which will correct the data types.

Answer (score 3):

As Ashley said, you can use the changeset with an custom function, like this:

```
def changeset(struct, params) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name]) # your fields
  |> team_id_to_integer()
end

def team_id_to_integer(changeset) do
  team_id = get_field(changeset, :team_id)

  if is_bitstring(team_id) do
    put_change(changeset, :team_id, String.to_integer(team_id)
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```